All correlations meta-analysis
I am new with MetaSEM. I am trying to fit a simple meta-analysis (I just want to analyse 2 correlations; see Figure).
Here you can find the code that I am using with some simulated data but if there are no regressions I cannot make it work (it goes forever unless I add a regression coeficient). It should be an easy model but I am stuck. I just want two covariances and I have fixed all the variances to one. In other words I just want to meta-analyse the correlations between S-D and I-D.
Correlations between S and D, S and I and D and I are stored here:
rSD <- c(0.85, 0.8, 0.90, 0.78, 0.70,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
rSI <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.85,NA,NA,NA,NA)
rDI <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.60, 0.50, 0.55, 0.60, 0.55)

rSI could be al NAs since I am not interested in that correlation.
I have read about SEM and RAM models and I think this model is identified and should be easily fitted. Any help and guidance would be really appreciated.
library(metaSEM)
source("http://www.suzannejak.nl/MASEM_functions.R")

rSD <- c(0.85, 0.8, 0.90, 0.78, 0.70,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
rSI <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.85,NA,NA,NA,NA)
rDI <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.60, 0.50, 0.55, 0.60, 0.55)




N <- c(10000,40000, 30000, 10000, 10000,20000,10000, 50000, 10000, 10000  )

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(rSD,rSI,rDI, N))


nvar <- 3
varnames <- c("S","D", "I")
labels <- list(varnames,varnames)

cormatrices <- readstack(data[,c(1,2,3)], no.var = nvar, var.names = varnames, diag = FALSE)

n <-  data$N

pattern.na(cormatrices, show.na=F)
pattern.n(cormatrices, n=n)


my.df <- Cor2DataFrame(cormatrices, n, acov = "weighted")


## Specify model using lavaan syntax
model <-
  '

# Covariances
D ~~ I
D ~~ S
# Variances

D ~~ 1*D
S ~~ 1*S
I ~~ 1*I
'

RAM1 <- lavaan2RAM(model, obs.variables=varnames)
RAM1




## Create the model implied correlation structure with implicit diagonal constraints
M0 <- create.vechsR(A0=RAM1$A, S0=RAM1$S)

## Create the heterogeneity variance-covariance matrix
T0 <- create.Tau2(RAM=RAM1, RE.type="Diag", Transform="expLog", RE.startvalues=0.05)

## Fit the model
mx.fit0 <- osmasem(model.name="No moderator", Mmatrix=M0, Tmatrix=T0, data=my.df)


## View the results
summary(mx.fit0, fitIndices = TRUE)
VarCorr(mx.fit0)



For meta-analyzing the correlations you do not really need to specify a SEM model. You could just meta-analyze the correlation matrices using the tssem1() function:
mx.fit0 <- tssem1(Cov=cormatrices, n=n, RE.type = "Zero")

In this example there are not enough data to estimate between-studies heterogeneity, therefore I set RE.type = "Zero", but in your real data RE.type = "Diag" could be better.
Note that the correlations were read in in the incorrect order, it should be:
cormatrices <- readstack(data[,c(1,3,2)], no.var = nvar, var.names = varnames, diag = FALSE)


Thank you so much, @SJaK. This is really helpful! Just out of curiosity, why does not the correlation model (SEM model with just double headed arrows but no regressions) work? I guess it follows the path tracing rules and it should be identified.  I would also need to add moderators. Is that possible ussing just tssem1()? Thank you so much in advance! With all good wishes, Juan

You can see the model as a saturated SEM model indeed, and it is identified. It is an implementation issue.
tssem1() does not facilitate including moderators, but you could fit the same model using the meta() function (see link). In your example the code for the (fixed-effects) analysis with a moderator 'mod' would be:
fit.mod <- meta(y=my.df$data[,c("D_S","I_S","I_D")], v=my.df$data[,4:9],     RE.constraints=matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=3), x = mod)

Thank you so much, again @SJaK. One final question. What would be the way to specify the model (if this is possible) using the lavaan syntax? To use the above code ( mx.fit0 <- osmasem(model.name="No moderator", Mmatrix=M0, Tmatrix=T0, data=my.df))For two variables I guess I could use a regression model (X~Y or Y~X) but for more variables I am not sure. Thank you for your wonderful feedback (and great webpage!)
